# How to input stdin data to spark script as input

Tags: python, linux, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a lot subdirectories in a folder that I have to process. I have decided find linux utility to find all files like

```
find . -name *.gz -exec zcat {} \;
```

Now I have to give stdout data to the spark scripts as input like following

```
find . -name *.gz -exec zcat {} \; | ./run_pyspark.py
```

Is it possible for spark to read stdin data (like in simple python). Please given some example or method atleast ?

Comment: Note: This won't work in a distributed environment.

Comment: I know but I am have to use it on same system (local mode)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
import subprocess
file_data=subprocess.call(['find', '.', '-name','*.gz',.....])
```

Answer (score 0):

A trick you can use is passing your arguments through the pipe process. Referring to the documentation

> pipe(command, env=None, checkCode=False)
>   Return an RDD created by piping elements to a forked external process.

```
>>> sc.parallelize(['1', '2', '', '3']).pipe('cat').collect()`
[u'1', u'2', u'', u'3']`
```

So you could have something like this in your script:

```
test = sc.parallelize([1])
data = test.pipe("find . -name *.gz -exec zcat {}")
```

However, this is not very efficient. If all you want is to be able to read all gzip files in your directory, simply pass the path to your files like

```
data = sc.textFile("/path/to/files/*gz")
data.take(3) ## take a sample of records
```

It's as simple as that. Also works with bz2 files.